# PHP object-oriented concept in file handling

Tags: php

I want to read content from a text file and download it into a pdf file using PHP object orientation. How I read content from a file, is it same as simple PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to get a file’s contents is [`file_get_contents`](http://docs.php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$contents = file_get_contents('filename');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know how to get the contents of a file using object-oriented notation, or how to store the contents as an object, or how to move the contents into a pdf?

Assuming the last 2:

```
//First set the file path and get the contents of the file:
$textfile->path = "path/to/file.txt";
$textfile->contents = file_get_contents($textfile->path);

//Next create the pdf, both as a handler and as a file on disk:
$pdf = PDF_new();
PDF_begin_document($pdf, "file.pdf", "");

//Then put the text file contents into the pdf:
PDF_show($pdf, $textfile->contents);

//Finally, save and close the pdf:
pdf_save($pdf); 
pdf_close($pdf);
```

If you want the script to return the pdf from a request and not save it to the server, simply change `"file.pdf"` to `""` and use the `header()` function to set the filename.